# The recording of takeoffs and landings in a logbook, particularly in the context of multipilot operations?

Tags: easa-regulations, logging, currency

It has recently occurred to me that I may not be correctly documenting my takeoff and landings in my logbook. I am currently using a paper logbook (until I unfreeze my ATPL) and have been creating a duplicate spreadsheet as a backup.

However, I have recently decided to switch to a popular logbook app instead of using the spreadsheet. I set up the app with the default settings, indicating my role as a First Officer in an airline. As a pilot of Boeing 737s, I have been recording all the landings I make, whether I am the pilot flying or the pilot monitoring. My rationale is that these TOs/LDGs should be recorded within my total TOs/LDGs, as the responsibility for takeoffs and landings lies with both crew members. However, I have noticed that the logbook app only registers the takeoff or landings when I am the Pilot Flying.

I am curious to know if there are any specific EASA regulations regarding the documentation of takeoffs and landings.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Logging a landing when you are not sole manipulator of the controls seems highly unethical at best.

Comment: @Michael Hall Hmm not sure if I would agree. The 737 is not designed to be flown single pilot ops. My presence in the flight deck and distinct SOPs for pilot monitoring make me an indispensable contributor to that approach/landing (and takeoff for that matter).

Comment: For example. As pilot monitoring, I call if the approach is stable or unstable at the landing gate. I manipulate the flaps, I lower the gear, I put the engine start switches in continuous, I put the engine anti ice on, I do a RECALL, I run the landing checklist….

Comment: I don't disagree that you are a valuable and required member of the crew, only that "monitoring" is not  flying.  By definition.  It wouldn't even cross my mind to log a landing when monitoring.

Comment: Have you asked your Chief pilot or other crews how they do it?  Does your company SOP address it?

Comment: @MichaelHall, you might get a kick out of this. For the boat, a copilot/NFO can log arrested landings as type Y (day) or Z (night). I don’t know of any pilot that did it, but it was possible.

Comment: Our NFO's did it.  For the patch.  Caused plenty of eyerolls amongst the single seat guys.  (and, quietly, the single anchor guys in our own squadron...)

Comment: Is there ***any*** requirement to have PM'd a landing or a number of landings, in the past XX days?  Can one be current to land as PF but not as PM?  While I fly in FAA-land and not EASA-land, any count of landings as PM is entirely in the "useless trivia" category, and isn't tracked by our airline nor anybody else I've ever heard of. Maybe EASA differs. The paper copy is your book, track anything you want to, but claiming (intentionally or not) a PM'd landing as if you were the PF can get people in major trouble in most places.

Comment: @RalphJ, Well said!  If you were to edit that into an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @MichaelHall Thanks, but EASA can have enough differences from FAA that extrapolating from the one to the other doesn't really make for a great answer.  Especially given what we now have below, quoting EASA regs as definitively "landing" = "PF landing."

Comment: I didn't see bus driver's newest answer.  That sticks a fork in the issue, even if it is a bit too brief in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

See EU FCL.050.

“column 8: indicate the number of landings performed as pilot flying by day or night;”

https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf#page39

Answer (score 3):

Your logbook must contain enough information to determine whether you meet the relevant recency requirements of your certificate.

The wording of this is not super clear in EASA regulations. From FCL.060:

> A pilot shall not operate an aircraft
> in commercial air transport or carrying passengers [...] as PIC or co-pilot unless he/she has carried out, in the preceding 90 days, at least 3 take-
> offs, approaches and landings in an aircraft of the same type or class or an FFS representing
> that type or class. The 3 take-offs and landings shall be performed in either multi-pilot or
> single-pilot operations, depending on the privileges held by the pilot.

Which leaves open the question of what counts as "carrying out" a takeoff, approach, and landing. From the night recency requirements in the following paragraph (emphasis mine):

> [A pilot shall not operate] as PIC at night unless he/she [...] has carried out in the preceding 90 days at least 1 take-off, approach and landing
> at night as a **pilot flying** in an aircraft of the same type or class or an FFS
> representing that type or class

Night recency specifies "pilot flying." By implication "carrying out" does not imply that you are the pilot flying, and so the pilot monitoring can log the takeoffs, approaches, and landings towards their recency requirements.

Note that this is a deviation from ICAO. The relevant ICAO documentation is crystal clear that you must be the pilot flying for it to count. From Annex 6, Part I, Section 9.4.1.1:

> The operator shall not assign a pilot-in-command or a co-pilot to operate at the flight controls of a type or
> variant of a type of aeroplane during take-off and landing unless that pilot has operated the flight controls during at least three
> take-offs and landings within the preceding 90 days on the same type of aeroplane or in a flight simulator approved for the
> purpose.

It would be a good idea to log PF and PM landings separately, since if you fly outside of EASA airspace you may be beholden to the more restrictive currency requirements of the relevant country. You need to distinguish between PF and PM for night recency anyway.

Comment: I agree there is some ambiguity in what "carrying out" could mean.  However, in my opinion it would be construed by EASA authorities as "manipulating" the flight controls.   Physically managing the flight controls, thrust levers, steering after touchdown or during takeoff, brakes, reverse thrust are proficiency/currency based skills.  Doing PNF/PM duties, important as they are, aren't a substitute for maintaining the full spectrum of landing/takeoff skills. The term "carried out" (FCL.060), I believe would ultimately be interpreted and carry the same meaning as the ICAO and U.S. language.

Comment: I'm with 757toga on this. Sometimes it is safe to infer that something is permitted by omission of a specific qualifying statement, but here, (*especially if you throw in CFR 61.57*) there are multiple references to establish the intent that the pilot flying is the only one performing the landing, and therefore should be the only one to log it. Obviously the App developers also see it that way.

Comment: Excellent answer, I just disagree with the interpretation: "*By implication "carrying out" does not imply that you are the pilot flying, and so the pilot monitoring can log the takeoffs, approaches, and landings towards their recency requirements.*"  Odd perhaps, because I generally favor the most advantageous and liberal interpretation.  I guess it stems from my personal aversion to taking credit, (or blame) for any landing when someone else had the controls.

Comment: @757toga Interestingly, the EASA regulations require this recency to "operate" the aircraft, whether as PF or PM, whereas ICAO/FAA only requires recency to manipulate the flight controls/act as PIC. This is, in my opinion, another point in favor of the idea that PM duties count for recency, since you require the recency even to act as PM. It makes some sense- if you're going to act as PM on landing, what better way to stay proficient is there than acting as PM on some landings?

Comment: But in any case I agree it's not 100% clear, and any pilot would be wise to confer with their local authorities before relying on any legal interpretations they read on the internet. ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall I would be curious to see any EASA references that establish the intent that the PF is the one performing the landing. Obviously that is the case in the US and most other ICAO countries, but it would hardly be the first case where EASA has dramatically different rules from many other authorities.

Comment: Chris, all good points. But the idea that someone can satisfy the incredibly minimal standard of 3 takeoff/lndgs in a 90 day period as the PNF and be considered proficient seems, to me, as unreasonable in the practical sense. By that standard, unlikely as it may be, someone could go months and months never touching the flight controls and be considered current and proficient. Think about the skills necessary for a visual approach, proper glide path, x-wind, flare, short rwy, etc. But, again just my opinion from having flown Boeings for many years.

Comment: @757toga It is important not to confuse recency/currency with proficiency. Do you feel that someone who acts as PF for only one landing a month is likely to remain proficient?

Comment: The purpose, in my opinion, of recency/currency is to remain proficient.  But, as I indicate in a previous comment, 3 takeoffs/lndgs (including or in addition to 1 at night) every 90 days is an incredibly minimal standard. Fortunately, in airline ops, getting more than 3 takeoffs and landings as the PF is rarely a problem.

Comment: @757toga I agree, it's a very minimal standard. I would hope that most airline pilots have many more than 3 takeoffs and landings in 3 months! Preferably both as PF and as PM.

Comment: "*I would be curious to see any EASA references that establish the intent that the PF is the one performing the landing.*"  Well, the reference you provided on night landings states "pilot flying" clearly.  You even bolded it.  It is the omission of this same phrase in the first quote that leads you to infer that during the day time both pilots are considered to have performed the landing.

Comment: @MichaelHall By that logic, FAA day currency requires three landings to a full stop. ;)

Comment: Touche!  Well played my friend.  I disagree of course, but don't have a snappy comeback ready...